# Ghost Reputation

Tags: support, reputation

I answered a very old question here: [Best way to setup USB mic as system default on Raspbian Jessie](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37177/best-way-to-setup-usb-mic-as-system-default-on-raspbian-jessie)

As I had just encountered (and solved) the problem myself, so I though I'd answer the question anyway.

A few hours after I answered it I got +3 reputation from it, but no one had up-voted or accepted my answer. Furthermore, about 10 minutes later I got +2 more reputation from that same question, and again no one had up-voted nor accepted the answer.

My question is: where is this reputation coming from?

Comment: The +2 came from an edit you made and that was accepted. I don't see where you got +3 on that question. However if you go to your profile page and click on the reputation heading in the left column you can see all of your reputation changes, For a full list of how you gain and lose reputation see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: @SteveRobillard ah, it shows the edit but it doesn't show where the +3 came from, but it shows up in my notifications bar.

Comment: Like I said, no clue on that one can you post a pic maybe it is a bug.

Comment: @SteveRobillard yep, give me one minute

Comment: @SteveRobillard Now it says the +3 is from a different question. Maybe I read it wrong the other times..? Well I guess I'm crazy, thanks for the help anyways!

Comment: +3 is still odd the only time I see strange numbers like that is if I downvote something my next upvote will show as +9 instead of 10 perhaps you had 2 downvotes and an upvoted question.

Comment: @SteveRobillard That's quite possible, I'm not sure if I down voted anything, but I might have

Comment: +5 (question upvoted) + -2 (question downvoted) = 3.  This is how you can end up making rep on a negative score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a [full accounting of your reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/33979/patrick-cook?tab=reputation&sort=post) on your profile. Yesterday has the following entries:

```
+10 21:13   upvote  How to make a clean python installation
+10 11:24   upvote  Why did my Pi die?
+2  03:51   edit    Best way to setup USB mic as system default on Raspbian Jessie
+10 03:34   upvote  How much current should I supply my 2 model B?
+10 02:48   upvote  Raspbian doesn't find external hdd at boot
```

I couldn't find any other reputation events that add up to +3. The most likely scenario is a question upvote and a downvote. But that doesn't seem to be the situation here.

Is it possible that you mis-saw the notification?